# UIViewController rotates view but doesn't resize it

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I recently added a UIViewController to my iOS game, and I am having some difficulties. I have my view added to the view controller and when I rotate my phone the view rotates to stay upright. My problem is that the view stays in portrait mode when it is supposed to be in landscape, the bottom is off screen and nothing is drawn to the right of the screen.

This is the code for my UIViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        _glView = [[[OpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
        [self.view addSubview:_glView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is your OpenGLView class but you may try to set `autoresizingMask` of your `_glView` to `(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)` if this is some UIView derivative.

Comment: Yes, it is from UIView. And your code did work. But the contents of my view have poor quality width-wise (This is for OpenGL) which tells me that my game is drawn fitted into the portrait orientation and then stretched. Would this be that OpenGL is being drawn in portrait? How would I make it Landscape?

Comment: It looks to me like `glViewport` is not resized automatically, perhaps you need to do it manually in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`. If you do so remember to update your projection matrix as well. Perhaps your `OpenGLView` class has some convenient method like `resize` or `reshape` unless it's your own implementation.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I was changing the values of my projection matrix only, I totally forgot about glViewport. You sir, are a life saver.